# Using Beautiful Soup to Extract Nested Data in HTML

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm building a web scraper for housing prices in the United States. An example of the data that I'm using can be found [here](https://www.bestplaces.net/cost_of_living/zip-code/california/san_diego/92128). I'm trying to extract the data for the specific zip code (Studio: $1420, 1 Bedroom: $1560).

Here is the HTML portion of what I am trying to extract:

```
<tspan x="5" y="16" class="highcharts-text-outline" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2px" stroke-linejoin="round" style="">$1420</tspan>
```

When I try to use BeautifulSoup4, I this is what I have:
    import urllib.request  as urllib2 
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
# specify the url
quote_page = 'https://www.bestplaces.net/cost_of_living/zip-
code/california/san_diego/92128'

# query the website and return the html to the variable ‘page’
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)


soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
price = soup.find('tspan', attrs={'class': 'highcharts-text-outline'})

print(price)
```

But this returns nothing. I am wondering how I can change my command to properly extract this.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to parse a dynamic content using `urllib` library which is unable to do the job. You need to use any browser simulator like `selenium` to deal with that. Here is how you can go using `selenium`:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from contextlib import closing

with closing(Chrome()) as driver:
    quote_page = 'https://www.bestplaces.net/cost_of_living/zip-code/california/san_diego/92128'
    driver.get(quote_page)
    price = driver.find_element_by_class_name('highcharts-text-outline').text
    print(price)
```

Output:

```
$1420
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `text` attribute:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
s = '<tspan x="5" y="16" class="highcharts-text-outline" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2px" stroke-linejoin="round" style="">$1420</tspan>'
result = soup(s, 'lxml').find('tspan').text
```

Output:

```
u'$1420'
```

Comment: I am actually feeding in the URL via urllib, and when I get the HTML data from the website, this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
price = soup.find('tspan',{'class':['highcharts-text-outline']})

price.text
```

Comment: I edited my comment to include all my code. When I try this, it still doesn't work.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.